# grails quartz job never gets executed

Tags: grails, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz-core

I have this job:

```
class MyJob {
    static triggers = {
      cron name:"some job", cronExpression:"0 0 * * * ? *"
    }

    def execute() {
        log.info "job runs"
    }
}
```

The job should run every hour. I thought that the problem is the cronExpression. That's why I changed it to the expression above. Before I had this expression:

```
0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *
```

But none of the expressions work.

My setup:

I have 10 jobs that run between every 5 minutes to once per month.
Every job seems to run except this one...

My questions:

1. Why is the job not executed?
2. Is there a max_jobs parameter that is responsible for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try without year:

   ```
   static triggers = {
       cron name: 'myTrigger', cronExpression: "0 0 0-23 * * ?"
   }
   ```
2. You can control it f.e. by predicting time of execution and preparing proper expression (it triggers only twice a month; on first day of month at 1.00 and 2.00 am):

   ```
   static triggers = {
       cron name: 'myTrigger', cronExpression: "0 0 1-2 1 * ?"
   }
   ```

   Read more about [different types of triggers](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/triggers.html):

> Currently plugin supports three types of triggers:
>
> - simple — executes once per defined interval (ex. “every 10 seconds”);
> - cron — executes job with cron expression (ex. “at 8:00am every Monday through Friday”);
> - custom — your implementation of Trigger interface.

Remember also about:

> The triggers name property must be unique across all triggers in the
>   application.
>
> By default, jobs will not be executed when running under the test
>   environment.

More examples you can find [here](http://grails.asia/grails-quartz-plugin-tutorial).

Comment: I just checked your first answers (0 0 * * * ?). Because it was just full hour. It doesn't trigger.I dont understand what you want to say with your second answer. Could you say it in other words

Comment: I am using 1.0.2. I enabled the execution on all environments. Names are unique

Comment: I doubled checked --> looks like 2 jobs have the same trigger name. I have fixed it and will check if the job runs on full hour

Comment: yes. thank you. I had 2 trigger names that where equal. The job runs now